# Python loop that writes files from requests with going trough a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, request

I am trying to write a loop that gets .json from an url via requests, then writes the .json to a .csv file. Then I need it to it over and over again until my list of names (.txt file) is finished(89 lines). I can't get it to go over the list, it just picks the bottom name of my list and then quits. I need it to go through and basically create 89 files, with the corrects urls. The other functions works properly, but it only does it once.

I can't seem to find a loop fitting for my purpose. Since I am a total beginner of python I hope I can get some help here and learn more

My code

```py
#Opens the file with pricelists

with open('prislistor.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        pricelists = (line.strip())

response = requests.get('https://api.example.com/3/prices/sublist/{}/'.format(pricelists), headers=headers)

#Formats it
parsed = json.loads(response.text)

listan=(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

#Converts and creates a .csv file.
data = parsed['Prices']

with open('listan-{}.csv'.format(pricelists), 'w') as outf:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(outf, data[0].keys())
    dw.writeheader()

    for row in data:
        dw.writerow(row)

print ("The file list-{}.csv is created!".format(pricelists))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python use indent (spaces, tabs) to mark code block, you need to put your looping logic INSIDE the loop block

```
#Opens the file with pricelists

with open('prislistor.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f): # from here on, a looping code block start with 8 spaces
        pricelists = (line.strip())
        # Keeps the indents
        response = requests.get('https://api.example.com/3/prices/sublist/{}/'.format(pricelists), headers=headers)

        #Formats it
        parsed = json.loads(response.text)

        listan=(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

        #Converts and creates a .csv file.
        data = parsed['Prices']

        with open('listan-{}.csv'.format(pricelists), 'w') as outf:
            dw = csv.DictWriter(outf, data[0].keys())
            dw.writeheader()

            for row in data:
                dw.writerow(row)

        print ("The file list-{}.csv is created!".format(pricelists))

    # codes here is outside the loop but still INSIDE the 'with' block, so you can still access f here

# codes here leaves all blocks
```

Comment: Worked like charm.